# Solving rational inequalities

Tags: functions, inequality

I am having difficulty with solving:

$$\frac{(2x-1)}{(x-5)} > \frac{(x+1)}{(x+5)}.$$

I tried to move the one side over so that there was zero opposite the equation but I ended up making some errors and just confusing myself.

Can anyone please give me a clue on solving this inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the sensible way to approach this inequality is to multiply both sides by $(x - 5)^2$, then $(x + 5)^2$.

Why the squares? If we multiply by just $x - 5$ and $x + 5$ (i.e. cross multiply) then we must keep track of whether we've multiplied by a positive or a negative number, and change the sign accordingly. That means we would have to assume three cases: $x < -5$, $-5 < x < 5$, and $x > 5$. That's horrible. Instead, if you multiply by squares, you're guaranteed to be multiplying by a positive. (Actually, you should be careful that you don't end up multiplying by $0$, so we should make sure we don't include the potential solutions $x = -5$ or $x = 5$. They won't make it in, but we should verify that they don't at the end.)

If you multiply both sides by $(x - 5)^2$, then $(x + 5)^2$, then you get,
$$(2x - 1)(x + 5)^2(x - 5) > (x + 1)(x + 5)(x - 5)^2.$$
Moving everything to one side,
$$(2x - 1)(x + 5)^2(x - 5) - (x + 1)(x + 5)(x - 5)^2 > 0.$$
Now we need to factorise this expression. I highly advise *not* expanding first, since we already can see common factors of $x + 5$ and $x - 5$. Factorising, we get,
\begin{align}
(x + 5)(x - 5)((2x - 1)(x + 5) - (x + 1)(x - 5)) &> 0 \\
(x + 5)(x - 5)(2x^2 + 9x - 5 - (x^2 - 4x - 5)) &> 0 \\
(x + 5)(x - 5)(x^2 + 13x) &> 0 \\
x(x + 5)(x - 5)(x + 13) &> 0.
\end{align}
At this point, I'd make a quick sketch of $y = x(x+5)(x-5)(x+13)$. It's a quartic polynomial (i.e. it's leading term is a multiple of $x^4$), which implies it'll limit to $\infty$ as $x \rightarrow \pm \infty$. It has roots $x = -13, -5, 0, 5$. The inequality holds when the graph is above the $x$-axis, which will be to the left of $-13$, between $-5$ and $0$, and to the right of $5$. If we write this answer using inequalities, we have,
$$x < -13 \text{ or } -5 < x < 0 \text{ or } x > 5,$$
or in interval notation,
$$(-\infty, -13) \cup (-5, 0) \cup (5, \infty).$$
Notice that $-5$ and $5$ are not included in the solution, as we needed.

Comment: Somehow things got flipped...these are the regions where the inequality is false.  If you take a huge positive (or huge negative x) it is clear that the inequality is true.

Comment: Ah yep, I just reversed the inequality in my head when interpreting the graph. Whoops! I'll correct that now.

Answer (score 1):

What makes problems like this hard is the fact that it is not easy to cross-multiply.  Every time you multiply both sides of an inequality you need to carefully check the sign of the multiplier...if you are multiplying by a negative number you need to flip the inequality.  For a problem like this, you can go case by case.  As an alternative, you can note that the only values of x for which the inequality can change direction are those values for which either one side or the other is singular (as in division by 0) or for which the terms are equal.  The singularities occur when x is 5 or -5.  The equalities occur at x = 0 (both sides are $\frac15$) or x = -13 (both sides are $\frac32$).  Thus there are only 5 intervals to consider:  $$(-\infty,-13)\;\; (-13, -5)\;\; (-5,0) \;\;(0,5) \;\;(5,\infty)$$  Just picking particular values to try in each of the 5 intervals we see that your inequality alternates True, False, True, False, True.  So the intervals on which it is true are 
$$(-\infty,-13)\;\;\; (-5,0) \;\;(5,\infty)$$
(to illustrate:  to check, say, the interval (-13, -5) we try the value x = -10.  The lh of your inequality at x = -10 is $\frac75$ while the rh is $\frac{11}{6}$.  Clearly the rh is bigger so the inequality is false in this region.

Comment: Note:  I see from a comment you left that you may not know the meaning of the symbol $\infty$ .  This is just shorthand for "infinity".  the interval (5, $\infty$) means "all x > 5".  Similarly the interval (-$\infty$,-13) means "all x < -13".

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{2x-1}{x-5} - \dfrac{x+1}{x+5} > 0 \iff \dfrac{(2x-1)(x+5)-(x+5)(x-1)}{(x-5)(x+5)}>0 \iff \dfrac{x(x+5)}{(x-5)(x+5)}>0\iff x(x-5) > 0, x \neq -5\iff -\infty < x < -5 \cup-5 < x < 0 \cup x > 5 $.
So $x \in (-\infty, -5) \cup (-5,0) \cup (5,\infty)$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help with this question. I am just slightly confused however. You have the negative infinity sign included and also the U shape and I am not sure what that means...

Comment: Im still having trouble comprehending what that fully means. :$

Comment: It means that $x$ can only lie in any of the intervals described.

Comment: Ive just started grade 12 advanced functions so I have not yet encountered this symbol. Is there any way to solve the inequality without using such? :$

Comment: There are algebraic errors in this solution.  When the terms are put over a common denominator, the numerator is wrong.  Then, when the denominator is cleared (by multiplication presumably) the inequality should only stay as is when the denominator is positive, which it isn't always.